# Get Base64 data from handler message in android

Tags: android

send some image data in base64 and collect in hanlder and get message object in handler. 
How can collect that image base64 data in handler and how to change that data into byte array after that base64.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decode the base64 data to a byte array, use this [utility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: can you give more idea, and because have used utility for fetching the data in hanldermessage method..